# AMP date picker not working in FORM submission

Tags: amp-html

I am creating an AMP version of my website. 
My requirement is to use the available AMP-DATE-PICKER on a FORM field, and pass that DATE value selected by the user to another page. 
In the following code, the calndar pop-up is coming up fine, the date value is also getting correctly populated on the field, but clicking on the GO (submit) button does not do anything.

1) After selecting the date on the pop-up calendar, the calendar should disappear. It is not happening and the calendar is still visible.

2) After hitting the "Go" (submit) button, the page is not doing anything.

Have tried the following code:

The following is in the HEAD section:

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-date-picker" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-date-picker-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-lightbox" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-lightbox-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
```

and the following is at the place in BODY where the FORM field should appear:

```
<form method="post" action-xhr="https://example.com/process/getdate.php">&#9654;Select Date:<amp-date-picker id="simple-date-picker-2" type="single" mode="overlay" min="2017-04-17" layout="container" on="select:AMP.setState({date2: event.date, dateType2: event.id})" locale="en" format="YYYY-MM-DD" open-after-select input-selector="[name=date2]" class="example-picker space-between"><input size="8" class="border-none p0" name="date2" value="<?php echo date("dMY");?>"><button on="tap: simple-date-picker-2.submit">Go</button>
  </amp-date-picker>
</form>
```

1) The calendar pop-up correctly appears when I click on the FORM field. I expect that once the date is selected on the pop-up calendar, the calendar pop-up should disappear and leave the selected date on the FORM field.

2) After hitting Submit, the selected date value should be passed to the "getdate.php" page.

For reference, this is the [AMP documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-date-picker/?format=websites) I have consulted:

Answer (score 0):

> 1) After selecting the date on the pop-up calendar, the calendar should disappear. It is not happening and the calendar is still visible.

I don't think that's possible for the time being since the `date-picker` encloses the input you might want to add a feature request in the AMP project in Github.

> 2) After hitting the "Go" (submit) button, the page is not doing anything.

Because your code is wrong - `<button on="tap: simple-date-picker-2.submit">Go</button>` with this code you are trying to submit the `amp-date-picker` which you can't do it. Instead, you must add an ID to the `form` element, for example, `my_form` an then add it as a target once the button is clicked, like this:

`<form method="post"  id="my_form" action-xhr="https://example.com/process/getdate.php">`

`<button on="tap:my_form.submit" >Go</button>`

Although it will be easier to just add a `submit` button.